# Form submit with ajax request and custom middleware in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, form-submit

I use django+wagtail as my web platform and RESTapi as backend.

I have a 'user edit page' on my website with post form, which I send to API in order to verify applied changes.

And I have a custom middleware, which do smth with cache of wagtail app.

After form submission I need to do several things (if API responded with 'OK' status):

- Show smth like 'Changes are saved' on my webpage with form
- Edit smth in cache of my app

I have vague thoughts of the solution, based on custom http header, here is more accurate example:

- I submit the form and wait for the reposonse from API
- if the response is good I reload page with some custom header, which I catch in my middleware and

  - do what I want to do in cache
  - set some template tag, which I will check in template in order to show 'Changes are saved'

The problem now is: how to set this custom http header in js for a reloading page? If my approach is absolutely wrong - please give me heads up for something else, I am pretty new to web-development